# Select an iframe inside a shadow-root (closed)

Tags: javascript, iframe, shadow-dom

I want to obtain this iframe that it's inside a shadow-root (closed):

[image of shadow root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epxvV.png)

I have tried already multiple things like document.querySelector("iframe[style*='display:block']").innerHTML or document.querySelector("iframe[style*='display:block']") but none of this works.
How can I obtain this iframe?

Comment: You can't. Look closely, it says ``shadow-root (closed)`` You can only access ``open`` shadowRoots